# Is there a common term for class roles?

Tags: object-oriented-design, terminology

In object oriented design, we define solution domain with classes. We give a particular role to each class such as factory, data transfer object, serializer, validator, service, proxy, adapter, etc.

Do you know a common name for this concept rather than role?

Comment: "purpose, "function", "aspect", "part to play" ... but the key is that a class should have a single responsibility. The rest is semantics.

Comment: It is called "object oriented design".

Comment: @Euphoric Factory is an "object oriented design", serializer is an object oriented design" ... These look strange. Factory is a role, serializer is a role.. are better.

Comment: I would say "responsibility" is the more common term you are looking for. Role is more often used for people, like users. [edit] Oh, well. David Arno already implicitly mentioned it.

Comment: @MartinMaat For example, `FormFactory`is responsible for creating forms. `ProductFactory`is responsible for creating products. Now, If  they have the same responsiblities, then responsibility could be the answer. If not, we need another term.

Comment: Those classes describes design patterns used in your solution. When you open a solution and see "Factories" or "Services" folders you can recognize patterns used here. So maybe: `Desing pattern units`.

Answer (score 0):

> factory, data transfer object, serializer, validator, service, proxy, adapter,

Most of what you named here comes from `design patterns`.

This mean that when you call something a `factory/adapter/...` we expect it, not only to have one proper responsability, but to be built and be used in a specific way. So when I see a `factory/adapter/...` I don't only expect only that it respect its responsability but that it's API follow the standard way of doing it.

For instance if you have a `DTO` we may expect to have an `Adapter` that will convert it to the `Business Object` in the `Service` layer. Because of this I think that `responsability` while being true is too narrow, I would prefer `purpose`.

Aniway the best answer was given by @DavidArno in his comment :

> The key is that a class should have a single responsibility. The rest is semantics

Comment: You catched my point. If a class is an `Adapter` it should comply some constraints like implementing a target interface using an adaptee class. So, adapter is more than a responsibility. Your suggestion `purpose` looks smart although it isn't a common term.